# Blurring raster using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.3, pixel

I work with this JPG areal photograph and i need to blur this signed blue rectangle only:

[image]

I tried to decline the display quality in the display layer properties:

[image] 
[image]

but it not enough for me, because i need the raster to be very pixeled, for example like this pixeled raster:

[image]

Comment: You want to blur the blue rectangle only? or the whole image?

Comment: i have changed the raster- i need to blur the whole raster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would generate a new raster by right-clicking on the image in the Table of Contents and Data > Export Data.

[image]

Then change the cell size to something much less detailed, e.g. 10m or 100m etc. to suit.

[image]

The new output raster will be much more pixelated.  (Example below at 25m cell size)

[image]